# Trying to Show Length Value of listArray

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm learning how to develop with AngularJS for the first time for a class and I am trying to understand why I'm not getting an updated value of the length property and was hoping someone could help me understand why my code is not working and what I should be doing for it to update.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Grocery List</title>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app>
    <h1>My Grocery List</h1>
    <div ng-controller="MYController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="listItem" placeholder="Add Grocery Item" />
        <input type="submit" ng-click="addItem()" value="Save" />
        <h2>Items</h2>
        <ul ng-show="itemArray.length">
            <li ng-repeat="listItem in itemArray">
                {{ listItem }}
                <buton ng-click="deleteItem(listItem)">X</buton>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code in app.js

```
function MYController($scope) {
    $scope.listItem;
    $scope.itemArray = [];

    $scope.addItem = function() {
        $scope.itemArray.push($scope.listItem);
        $scope.listItem = '';
    }

    $scope.deleteItem = function(deletedItem) {
        var idx = $scope.itemArray.indexOf(deletedItem);
        $scope.itemArray.splice(idx, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: When is it not working? When you click add item? When you click delete item? What is the symptom of not working?

Answer (score 1):

In Angular when you make controller then it need to assign with a module

So here you will made your controller in js like below

```
angular.module('todoApp', []) 
 .controller('MYController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.listItem;

    $scope.itemArray = [];

    $scope.addItem = function() {
        $scope.itemArray.push($scope.listItem);
        $scope.listItem = '';
    }

    $scope.deleteItem = function(deletedItem) {
        var idx = $scope.itemArray.indexOf(deletedItem);
        $scope.itemArray.splice(idx, 1);
    }
});
```

And in HTML bootstrap angular like below   in body tag and use your controller

```
<body ng-app="todoApp">
```

See here for reference **https://angularjs.org/#add-some-control**

Comment: That's good for future reference and that we were going to get more into that next weeks activities but we are going over the very basic stuff right now.

Comment: So I"m just tyring to understand why the number isn't getting updated. (length). Everything else in my app works.

Answer (score 1):

I think there may be some confusion between the `listItem` in `ng-model="listItem"` and `ng-repeat="listItem in itemArray"`.  Try changing the second one to a different variable name like this:

```
        <li ng-repeat="item in itemArray">
            {{ item }}
            <button ng-click="deleteItem(item)">X</button>
        </li>
```

Also, change that first line in your controller `$scope.listItem;` to `$scope.listItem = '';`.

Answer (score 0):

assign module to angular app using this code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', [])
```

and

```
<html ng-app="plunker">
```

[see plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xUPOYSilchALSJnUuQpc?p=preview)